# HTML Canvas : Fill Arc based complex shape

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas

Below is a JSON structure which draws arcs with different start and end angle

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

var elementDetail =  {"element":[{"type":"ARC","x1":510,"y1":10,"x2":74.585653306513848,"y2":74.585653306514814,"r":1500,"xm":510,"ym":1510,"alpha":4.4178734952765524,"beta":4.71238898038469,"color":2},{"type":"ARC","x1":74.585653306514587,"y1":74.585653306514928,"x2":10,"y2":510,"r":1500,"xm":1510,"ym":510,"alpha":3.1415926535897931,"beta":3.43610813869793,"color":2},{"type":"ARC","x1":10,"y1":510,"x2":74.585653306514587,"y2":945.41434669348541,"r":1500,"xm":1510,"ym":510,"alpha":2.8470771684816563,"beta":3.1415926535897931,"color":2},{"type":"ARC","x1":74.585653306514871,"y1":945.41434669348541,"x2":510,"y2":1010,"r":1500,"xm":510,"ym":-490,"alpha":1.5707963267948966,"beta":1.8653118119030334,"color":2},{"type":"ARC","x1":510,"y1":1010,"x2":945.4143466934853,"y2":945.41434669348541,"r":1500,"xm":510,"ym":-490,"alpha":1.2762808416867597,"beta":1.5707963267948966,"color":2},{"type":"ARC","x1":945.41434669348541,"y1":945.41434669348541,"x2":1010,"y2":510,"r":1500,"xm":-490,"ym":510,"alpha":0,"beta":0.29451548510813697,"color":2},{"type":"ARC","x1":1010,"y1":510,"x2":945.41434669348519,"y2":74.585653306514132,"r":1500,"xm":-490,"ym":510,"alpha":5.9886698220714489,"beta":6.2831853071795862,"color":2},{"type":"ARC","x1":945.41434669348553,"y1":74.585653306514587,"x2":510,"y2":10,"r":1500,"xm":510,"ym":1510,"alpha":4.71238898038469,"beta":5.006904465492827,"color":2},{"type":"POINT","x1":510,"y1":510,"color":7}]}
    
ctx.beginPath();
elementDetail.element.map((elem, index) => {
  ctx.arc(elem.xm, elem.ym, elem.r, elem.alpha, elem.beta);  
})

ctx.closePath();
ctx.stroke();
ctx.fillStyle = "#6fd0ff";
ctx.fill();
```

```css
canvas{ zoom:.25}
```

```html
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="1200" height="1200"></canvas>
```

The shape that I need to obtain is this:

[image]

I was able to loop through the json and fill draw stroke but not able to fill color inside the shape

I need help to fill the shape with color

Thanks

Comment: post the code that you wrote that draw the shape.

Comment: this fills only the segment of the circle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To avoid weird results, in complex shapes , I would rather perform the drawing in two steps :

- **Solid body rendering**: draw and fill the shape
- **Outline rendering** : draw the shape outter stroke

> **Note** : When drawing arcs you need to know that `ctx.arc()` will create a `line` from the last coordinates of the current path, to the first position of the arc.
>   In order to avoid it, you need to call `moveTo()` to lift the drawing pen to the first position of the arc.

```js
var elementDetail =  {"element":[{"type":"ARC","x1":510,"y1":10,"x2":74.585653306513848,"y2":74.585653306514814,"r":1500,"xm":510,"ym":1510,"alpha":4.4178734952765524,"beta":4.71238898038469,"color":2},{"type":"ARC","x1":74.585653306514587,"y1":74.585653306514928,"x2":10,"y2":510,"r":1500,"xm":1510,"ym":510,"alpha":3.1415926535897931,"beta":3.43610813869793,"color":2},{"type":"ARC","x1":10,"y1":510,"x2":74.585653306514587,"y2":945.41434669348541,"r":1500,"xm":1510,"ym":510,"alpha":2.8470771684816563,"beta":3.1415926535897931,"color":2},{"type":"ARC","x1":74.585653306514871,"y1":945.41434669348541,"x2":510,"y2":1010,"r":1500,"xm":510,"ym":-490,"alpha":1.5707963267948966,"beta":1.8653118119030334,"color":2},{"type":"ARC","x1":510,"y1":1010,"x2":945.4143466934853,"y2":945.41434669348541,"r":1500,"xm":510,"ym":-490,"alpha":1.2762808416867597,"beta":1.5707963267948966,"color":2},{"type":"ARC","x1":945.41434669348541,"y1":945.41434669348541,"x2":1010,"y2":510,"r":1500,"xm":-490,"ym":510,"alpha":0,"beta":0.29451548510813697,"color":2},{"type":"ARC","x1":1010,"y1":510,"x2":945.41434669348519,"y2":74.585653306514132,"r":1500,"xm":-490,"ym":510,"alpha":5.9886698220714489,"beta":6.2831853071795862,"color":2},{"type":"ARC","x1":945.41434669348553,"y1":74.585653306514587,"x2":510,"y2":10,"r":1500,"xm":510,"ym":1510,"alpha":4.71238898038469,"beta":5.006904465492827,"color":2},{"type":"POINT","x1":510,"y1":510,"color":7}]}

let canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
let ctx = canvas.getContext("2d")

// draw the solid body
ctx.beginPath();
elementDetail.element.map((elem, index) => {     
  ctx.moveTo(0,0);
  ctx.arc(elem.xm, elem.ym, elem.r, elem.alpha, elem.beta);   
})
ctx.fillStyle = "#6fd0ff";
ctx.fill();
ctx.closePath();

// draw the outline
elementDetail.element.map((elem, index) => {  
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(elem.xm, elem.ym, elem.r, elem.alpha, elem.beta);   
  ctx.stroke();
})
ctx.closePath();
```

```css
canvas{ zoom:.25}
```

```html
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="1200" height="1200"></canvas>
```

Comment: What if the data contains both line and arc?

Answer (score 0):

Have you try to use `context.fillStyle="your shape colour"`?
I think you might use a path to build shape, so every time you start path, you need to assign a colour to every shape.
Try to draw arc and polygon seperately.

```
function drawGraphics(ctx){
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.fillStyle="#6fd0ff"
  elementDetail.element.reverse().map((elem, index) => {
      if(elem.type==="ARC"&&index<=8){
        ctx.arc(elem.xm, elem.ym, elem.r, elem.alpha, elem.beta); 
      }
  })
  ctx.stroke()
  ctx.fill();
  ctx.closePath();
}
```

Comment: elementDetail.element.map((elem, index) => {
    ctx.fillStyle = elem.color;
    ctx.arc(elem.xm, elem.ym, elem.r, elem.alpha, elem.beta);  
})

Comment: I have tried that too, still the same result. only the segment is filled

Comment: I have found  the main reason why there are only segments filled. It's because the direction of json itself is wrong. I've check the params in json. If you reverse the array, then it's ok to fill and stoke.